# SQL Server if exists update, without "else insert"

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-update

I have inherited the following situation in ASP.Net website + SQL server database:

There is a big table(many rows, many columns) with a unique index on a field called PartnerRef, varchar(50). It also has a primary key, int, let's call it UniqueId. For 8-10 years a lot of code was written relying on the uniqueness of PartnerRef field. Many places/queries using PartnerRef=@partnerRef criteria to find one specific record. All of the sudden, we received the news that partners will start re-using values, sometimes even after just one week, so a new record might have to be created, while another one already exists having the same PartnerRef. Removing the unique index and changing all the code is not an option right now due to time pressure. Quick solution I implemented, was to execute an update before every insert:

```
Update Table1 
set PartnerRef = PartnerRef + '_' + Cast(UniqueId as varchar(10)) 
where PartnerRef=@partnerRef;
Insert new record using @partnerRef;
```

So, the value of the field in a previous/existing record is changed and then the new record is created. The old record cannot be deleted so soon, but also the original value in the old record is not that important anymore after being reused, so I can modify it without any problem. The update query runs before every new insert, but most of the times(90% maybe) it does not change anything, a previous record with the same PartnerRef does not exist. Leaving aside the stupidity of the whole table structure situation, my actual question is about performance and optimization of the update process. Would there be any advantage from using an IF EXISTS UPDATE instead of the simple update?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE PartnerRef=@partnerRef) 
Update Table1 
set PartnerRef = PartnerRef + '_' + Cast(UniqueId as varchar(10)) where PartnerRef=@partnerRef;
```

Is there a better/quicker way to do this update, until we change the web application and remove the unique index to allow duplicates in PartnerRef? Thank you for any idea.

Comment: Rather than tamper with database structure with Primary Keys on a table. Why not add a field to encapsulate the functionality of a Partner Ref in an entirely new column and write functionality to cater for this. What is being communicated is a change of requirements and should be treated like any other change. 

You are adding a degree of overhead to an already working process. In order to get this portion of functionality to work you are proposing a change that may require a full re-rest of the entire system which in itself is time consuming.

Comment: The current software has to work until we have time to change it. How we'll change it is not important right now. My question is only about the temporary solution of updating the existing record, in order to be able to insert another one. The simple update statement I use right now works fine, but I want to know if there is a more efficient way to find/update the existing record, considering the current table structure, unique index, ...